# Laravel 4 how check if a route only comes/redirected from another route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Say i have `localhost/public/admin` that redirects immediately to `localhost/public/user/login`.

How am I going to get the `admin` value in `user/login`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to grab the referer and check if it is contains 'admin'. Try the following

```
$referer = Request::referer();
// or
// $referer = Request::server('HTTP_REFERER');

if (strpos($referer,'admin') !== false) {
    dd('coming from admin')
}
```

Edit #1: As pointed out by @tomvo you can also use `URL::previous()` instead of `Request::referer()` in L4

Edit #2: It's actually mispelled as `referer` instead of `referrer` as point out by @JamesF

Edit #3: In Laravel 5 the `Request::referer()` method doesn't seem to exist anymore, you can still get it by using `Request::header('referer')` as point out by @TheSerenin

Comment: which would be `URL::previous()` in L4

Comment: Looks like it's `Request::referer()` with one 'r' - strange mis-spelling in the original spec (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

Comment: In Laravel 5 the `Request::referer()` method doesn't seem to exist anymore, you can still get it by using `Request::header('referer');`

Comment: `Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')` helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45713501/470749