# Laravel allow route to be accessible only from another route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.4

I have `/signup/select-plan` which lets the user select a plan, and `/signup/tos` which displays the terms of services. I want `/signup/tos` to be only accessible from `/signup/select-plan`. So if I try to go directly to `/signup/tos` without selecting a plan, I want it to not allow it. How do I go about this?

Comment: in simple on that controller add auth constructor...

Comment: Are you storing data whether select plan has been selected?

Comment: @NitishKumar yes. and i want that data to persist even after a page refresh on /signup/tos. I only want that data to be deleted if the user goes to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor, or the route (if you are not using contructors), you can check for the previous URL using the global helper `url()`.

```
public function tos() {
    if ( !request()->is('signup/tos') && url()->previous() !=  url('signup/select-plan') ) {
        return redirect()->to('/'); //Send them somewhere else
    }
}
```

Comment: does this allow me to do a page refresh /signup/tos after coming from /signup/select-plan?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller of `/signup/tos` which returns the tos view just add the following code:

```
$referer = Request::referer();
// or
// $referer = Request::server('HTTP_REFERER');

if (strpos($referer,'signup/select-plan') !== false) {
//SHOW THE PAGE
}
else
{
dd("YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED")
}
```

What we are doing here is checking the HTTP referrer and allowing the page access only if user comes from select-plan

Comment: does this allow me to do a page refresh /signup/tos after coming from /signup/select-plan?

Comment: No I do not think it will allow you to do that.

Comment: Please go through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195987/laravel-4-how-check-if-a-route-only-comes-redirected-from-another-route

Answer (score 0):

You are need of sessions in laravel. You can see the following docs to get more info: [Laravel Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session)

First of all you need to configure till how much time you want to have the session variable so you can go to your directory `config/sessions.php` and you can edit the fields `'lifetime' => 120,` also you can set `expire_on_close` by default it is being set to false.

Now you can have following routes:

```
Route::get('signup/select-plan', 'SignupController@selectPlan');
Route::post('signup/select-token', 'SignupController@selectToken');
Route::get('signup/tos', 'SignupController@tos');
Route::get('registered', 'SignupController@registered');
```

Now in your `Signupcontroller` you can have something like this:

```
public function selectPlan()
{
    // return your views/form...
}

public function selectToken(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->put('select_plan_token', 'value');
    return redirect('/signup/tos');
}
```

Now in `signupController` `tos` function you can always check the session value and manipulate the data accordingly

```
 public function tos()
 {
     $value = $request->session()->get('select_plan_token');
     // to your manipulation or show the view.
 }
```

Now if the user is registered and you don't need the session value you can delete by following:

```
public function registered()
{
    $request->session()->forget('select_plan_token');
    // Return welcome screen or dashboard..
}
```

This method will delete the data from session. You can manipulate this. You won't be able to use in `tos` function as you are refreshing the page and you want data to persist. So its better to have it removed when the final step or the nextstep is carried out. Hope this helps.

**Note:** This is just the reference please go through the docs for more information and implement accordingly.